# Average of absolute value of inner product of two vectors of IID normal variables

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, expectation

Consider two identical independently distributed sets of complex normal variables $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^N, \{Y_i\}_{i=1}^N$, with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma$.

Can the following expectation value
$$ \mathbb E \left[\,\,\left\lvert
  \sum_{k=1}^N X_i^* Y_i
\right\rvert \,\,\right] $$
be computed analytically?

What if the variables are real instead of complex?

The result seems to increase with $\sqrt N$, as shown by the following numerical computation:
[image]

where for each dot the average is taken over a sample of 1000 different pairs of independent complex normal $N$-dimensional vectors.
The blue line is the best fit line, using as fit function $a+b\sqrt{x}$, and the parameters have been found in this case to be $a \approx -0.25$ and $b \approx 0.9$ (but of course these are only very rough estimates).

I can derive the expectation value of *the square* of the above absolute value, which is gives
$$ \mathbb E \left[ \,\, \left\lvert
  \sum_{k=1}^N X_i^* Y_i
\right\rvert^2 \,\, \right]
= N \sigma^4,
$$
for $\mu=0$.
The square root of this gives the observed $\sqrt N$ dependence, but of course in general $\mathbb E[A^2] \neq \mathbb E[A]^2$, so that the argument is very handwavy.

Is there a way to compute this expectation value?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $\mu=0$ and $\sigma=1$. The products $X_iY_i$ are i.i.d with expectation 0 and variance 1. By the central limit theorem 
$$ Z_N=\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} \sum_{i=1}^N X_iY_i \rightarrow Z$$
in law, with $Z \sim {\cal N}(0,1)$. 
We have $E(Z_N \bar{Z}_N)=
\frac{1}{N}\sum_i E(X_i{Y}_i \bar{X}_j \bar{Y}_j)=1$ (use independence).
Then $E\left(\;|Z_N|\; 1_{|Z_N|\geq R} \right)\ \leq \ E(|Z_N|^2/R)\leq 1/R$. This implies that
$$  E\left( \left|Z_N\right| \right) \rightarrow E(|Z|)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}=0.7978846...$$

When $\mu\neq 0$, $\sigma=1$ then $\mbox{ var} (X_iY_i)=1+2\mu^2$ and $E(X_iY_i)=\mu^2$ and 
$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{N (2\mu^2+1)}} \sum_{i=1}^N (X_iY_i -N\mu^2) \sim Z$$
or
$$ \sum_{i=1}^N X_iY_i  \sim N\mu^2 + \sqrt{N(2\mu^2+1)}Z$$
From this
$$ E\left(\left|\sum_{i=1}^N X_iY_i\right|\right)  \sim N\mu^2 + o(1/N^p)$$
for any $p>0$ (the rest goes exponentially fast to zero).

When $X_i$ and $Y_i$ take complex values only the case $\mu=0$ is affected. I assume variance $E|X_i|^2=E|Y_i|^2=1$ and that the variables take complex symmetric values. The CLT then gives a complex variable $Z=U+iV$ where $U\sim{\cal N}(0,\frac{1}{2})$ and $V\sim{\cal N}(0,\frac{1}{2})$ are independent. Then
$$ E(|Z|)=\frac{1}{\pi} \int\int e^{-(u^2+v^2)} |u+iv| du\; dv =\frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{\infty}  e^{-r^2} r \cdot r\; dr\; d\phi$$
Thus, $$E(|Z|)=2\int_0^\infty e^{-r^2} r^2\; dr=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}=0.88622...$$
possibly fitting better with your numerical estimate above.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! So this mean that in the limit $N \to \infty$, for $\sigma=1$ and $\mu=0$, the expectation value goes like $\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \sqrt N$ right? What about finite values of $N$, can anything be said in that case? Also, can this result be generalized to the case of complex variables, and/or i.i.d. variables with general variance $\sigma$?

Comment: Yes to the first (if I didn't mess up constants it should be  confirmed by numerics). For finite $N$ that's looks  hard as you probably need to know details of the law (before the limit). The result only uses i.i.d of the products $X_iY_i$ and finite variance so you may easily generalize

Comment: Unfortunately, CLT does not imply the convergence of moments, for example, $G_n/\sqrt{n}\to G$ in distribution with $G$ standard normal does not imply that $E(|G_n|)\sim\sqrt{n}\sqrt{2/\pi}$ (a further argument is needed).

Comment: @Did Right, thanks. It works for the sum of i.i.d variables as for the first part (I have added a short argument). For the second ($\mu\neq 0$) it is possibly not so clear how fast the  remainder goes to zero?

Comment: Sorry but being uniformly bounded in $L^1$ and converging in distribution (your "short argument", if I understand correctly) does not imply convergence in $L^1$.

Comment: @Did  Well, difficult to disagree. Thanks again.